# Can't create ViewModelProvider for detached fragment - how to get ViewModel in postExecute of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm getting such exception sometimes:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Can't create ViewModelProvider for detached fragment
```

What I'm doing is:
- I have activity with three fragments in it.
- In fragment, I'm creating AsyncTask and in doInBackground method I'm making http request and in postExecute I'm adding item to database using ViewModel
- I'm getting exception in that line:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(MyFragment.this).get(MyViewModel.class)
```

In most cases it works fine. Could you help me how to improve that code to make it work in all cases?

Comment: you're leaking asynctask (not killing it alongside fragment detachment)

Comment: I do not want to kill it, because I want it to finish that task and in the end it should insert data to database